# Properly isolating components in React/Redux app, but permit passing callbacks between each others

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, react-redux

I just started learning React with Redux, so please, be lenient.
I followed the Redux kinda getting started, and so far, so good. But following along 'basic' and 'advanced' redux doc sections, I'm ending in a position where all my components are isolated. Which is perfectly fine. Except that one of my component is designed to display notifications, dismiss and remove them.
The other one is a modal which needs 4 parameters to work : one with the header text section, same for the body, one boolean to set if its displayed or not, and one to trigger a confirm action when confirm button is clicked.
My notifications component needs the modal to display when the user wants to remove a notification. Both components have a state handled with redux.

Here are some pieces.

Below, the notifications reducer, which handles dismissing deleting and fetching the notifications. Quite simple.

```
// The notifications reducer
let initialState = {
  isFetching: false,
  didInvalidate: false,
  notifications: []
}

const notifications = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'DISMISS':
      return {...state, notifications: state.notifications.map(element => element.id === action.id ? {...element, dismissed: !element.dismissed} : element)}
    case 'DISMISS_ALL':
      return {...state, notifications: state.notifications.map(element => { return {...element, dismissed: false} }) }
    case 'DELETE':
      return {...state, notifications: state.notifications.filter(element => element.id !== action.id)}
    case 'DELETE_ALL':
      return {...state, notifications: []}
    case 'INVALIDATE':
      return {...state, didInvalidate: true}
    case 'REQUEST':
      return {...state, isFetching: true, didInvalidate: false}
    case 'RECEIVE':
      return {...state, isFetching: false, didInvalidate: false, notifications: action.posts, lastUpdate: action.receivedAt}
    default:
      return state
  }
}

export default notifications
```

Then the notifications actions. The focus to me here, is on the `deleteNotification` and the `deleteAllNotifications`actions which must bind the modal opening and wait for its response, then trigger the removing, and only after that.
Those ones would need (I'm guessing) to work like the `fetchNotifications` action, calling another action (modal's one), instead of making a data fetching like this is the case for `fetchNotifications`.

```
// The notifications actions
//@flow
import axios from 'axios'

/**
 * NOTIFICATIONS ACTION CREATORS
 */
export const dismissNotification = (id: number) => {
  return { type: 'DISMISS', id }
}
export const dismissAllNotifications = () => {
  return { type: 'DISMISS_ALL' }
}
export const deleteNotification = (id: number) => {
  return { type: 'DELETE', id }
}
export const deleteAllNotifications = () => {
  return { type: 'DELETE_ALL' }
}

/**
 * DATABASE NOTIFICATIONS ACTION CREATORS
 */
export const invalidate = (uri: string) => {
  return { type: 'INVALIDATE', uri }
}
export const requestNotifications = (uri: string) => {
  return { type: 'REQUEST', uri }
}
export const receiveNotifications = (uri: string, json: string) => {
  return {
    type: 'RECEIVE',
    uri,
    posts: json,
    receivedAt: Date.now()
  }
}
export const fetchNotifications = (uri: string) => {
  return (dispatch: any) => {
    dispatch(requestNotifications(uri))
    return axios.get(uri)
      .then(
        response => response.data,
        error => console.log('Error', error) // TODO logger les erreurs
      )
      .then(json => {
        dispatch(receiveNotifications(uri, json))
      })
  }
}
```

Finally, the modal's reducer. The point here for the reducer is to handle the displaying (visible or not), the texts in it via `headerMessage` and `bodyMessage`.
The `id` is here to tell the modal if it has to dispatch a delete on a signle element or a whole bunch of it. And this is dirty to me. It should just return a confirm for instance, the one which will be catched by the notifications action as a response.

```
let initialState = {
  showModal: false,
  headerMessage: '',
  bodyMessage: '',
  id: false
}

const modal = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'MODAL_DISPLAY':
      return {...state,
        showModal: action.showModal,
        headerMessage: action.headerMessage,
        bodyMessage: action.bodyMessage,
        id: action.id
      }
    case 'MODAL_HIDE':
      return {...state,
        showModal: action.showModal,
        headerMessage: action.headerMessage,
        bodyMessage: action.bodyMessage,
        id: action.id
      }
    default:
      return state
  }
}

export default modal
```

Just to be clear, the modal component and the notifications component are living in different directories. I want the modal component to be usable in any context. Here this is about notifications, but if I want it to work with any other component than the notifications one, lets say the user's profile, I souldn't be tied to any component specifically.

In my case, the notifications component is the one which call the modal. This is it that 'drives' the global behaviour. But I guess I didn't build all this that well. Here is my notifications component index :

```
//@flow

import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk'
import { createLogger } from 'redux-logger'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux'
import { fetchNotifications } from './store/actions/NotificationsActions'
import NotifiationsApp from './store/reducers/reducerCombiner'
import App from './components/App'
import ModalContainer from '../modal-component/store/containers/ModalContainer'

const loggerMiddleware: any = createLogger()
const composeEnhancers: any = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose
const store: any = createStore(
  NotifiationsApp,
  composeEnhancers(
    applyMiddleware(
      thunkMiddleware,
      loggerMiddleware
    )
  )
)

store.dispatch(fetchNotifications('/app_dev.php/notifications/load?offset=0&limit=10'))

render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <div>
      <App/>
      <ModalContainer />
    </div>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('notifications-component')
)
```

As you can see, I'm calling the `ModalContainer` which is in facts, the 'smart' modal component abstraction.
And finally, here is my bad ; the `ModalContainer` which ties itself to the notifications component, where I'd like to 'return' the confirmation event when `onConfirm` is fired :

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { deleteAllNotifications, deleteNotification } from '../../../notifications-component/store/actions/NotificationsActions'
import { hideModal } from '../actions/ModalActions'
import ModalInstance from '../../components/Modal'

const getModalProperties = modal => {
  return modal
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return getModalProperties(state.modal)
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    onCancel: () => {
      dispatch(hideModal(false, false, '', ''))
    },
    onConfirm: id => { // BELOW, THIS IS VERY BAD!!
      id ? dispatch(deleteNotification(id)) : dispatch(deleteAllNotifications())
      dispatch(hideModal(false, '', '', false))
    }
  }
}

const ModalDisplay = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(ModalInstance)

export default ModalDisplay
```

I'm struggling on this one. Please, help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether I understood correctly, but it seems you're looking for `ownProps`. You want to pass a function to your `ModalWindow` component, which shall be called after the confirmation function has been called, right? So that you have an interface like

```
<ModalContainer onConfirm={myHandler}/>
```

In this case, your `mapDispatchToProps` needs to consider the props you passed to the container, like

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => {
  return {
    onCancel: () => {
      dispatch(hideModal(false, false, '', ''))
    },
    onConfirm: id => { // BELOW, THIS IS VERY BAD!!
      id ? dispatch(deleteNotification(id)) : dispatch(deleteAllNotifications())
      dispatch(hideModal(false, '', '', false));
      ownProps.onConfirm && ownProps.onConfirm(id);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track in general.  Conveniently, I just published [Practical Redux, Part 10: Managing Modals and Context Menus](http://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2017/07/practical-redux-part-10-managing-modals/), which demonstrates how to build and control modals, context menus, and notifications using Redux.  That includes how to handle "return values" from modals as they're closed.

To specifically answer your question: the handling of the ID for clearing one notification vs all of them doesn't seem "dirty" or "bad" to me at all - that approach should be fine.